# Why NLog.LogManager.Configuration returns null?

Tags: .net, configuration, nlog

In my project I got an `NLog.config` file but when I debug the `Main` method on my project `NLog.LogManager.Configuration` is null.

How can I make sure that the `NLog.config` will be found?

Comment: Is the config file set to copy on build/compile in the project?

Comment: @JAZ No it is not, it is set as content, however I changed it to be copied to the output directory and that helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is no config loaded, `NLog.LogManager.Configuration` will return `null`.

There could be various reasons why the config is not loaded, check the [troubleshooting steps](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting) for finding the reason.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I have just changed NLog.config property `"Copy to output directory" = "Copy if newer"`
from `"Do not copy"`.